# How to clone a full fledged MSCRM 4.0 OnPremise installation?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, hyper-v

Is there a clean way to duplicate/clone/copy a full fledged MSCRM 4.0 machine and bring back the copy with new host name?

Lets assume my crm installation runs on a host called crm01. Lets assume furthermore that this machine is a virtual machine. The goal is now to bring back a renamed clone of that machine  to live, for instance renamed to crm02.

After cloning that virtual machine, what else do I need to do?

I know that I have to pay attention to SQLServer, Reporting Services, IIS and MSCRM itself, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. Is there any reason you can't bring up your new virtual, install CRM on it, and point it to your existing org?

Comment: Hi Polshgiant, there is no specific reason other than time needed to ramp up new crm machines. Why install everything new each time if one can clone everything, right?